# Passing url to getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

getJSON works ok if I use json file locally, but I don't understand why can't I obtain it from external source?

For example:

```
$.getJSON('http://ninsuna.elis.ugent.be/rdf/data/tennis/Roland_Garros-25.05.2009-RogerFederer-RobinSoderling-set1-game1?output=json', 
function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Loaded.');
});
```

The [link](http://ninsuna.elis.ugent.be/rdf/data/tennis/Roland_Garros-25.05.2009-RogerFederer-RobinSoderling-set1-game1?output=json) outputs clean json file, but the method can't load it, in Firebug the response field is empty (unlike when I switch to local .json file).

Comment: It's called the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: You need server side code to send the request and act as proxy to your client side code.

Comment: For security reasons you can't do this, you need to use the JSONP hack instead. Can't say I'm too experienced with that but there's stuff about JSONP in the getJSON docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This violates the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The exception to this rule is to use JSONP however the remote server needs to support the slightly different response format.

Comment: True. Once you find JSONP service that returns what you need, here is [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ddvth/) using digg service.